# Error en DJANGO y CPANEL, No puedo subir archivo en admin de django , Models

Tags: django

Resulta que tengo un problema al configurar mi aplicación de django al Cpanel, al momento de subir la aplicación a cpanel, me genera todo normal, se visualiza el css de la página y todos los templates sin algún error, configuré la base de datos en MYSQL e igualmente todo iba bien, pero al momento de querer subir un archivo ya sea documento o imagen, se queda cargando hasta que da el error:

> Request Timeout
> This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

Intenté varias cosas como cambiar la configuración del htacces y php.ini de django para aumentar el tiempo en el que se cargan los archivos pero no logré nada hasta que se me ocurrió probar algo, borrar la opción de subir archivos del models de las publicaciones (les comparto el código):

```
class BolsaDeEmpleo(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    cargar_archivo = models.FileField(upload_to='media',blank=True,null=True)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    STATUS = [
        (0, "Publicado"),
        (1, "Ocultar"),
    ]
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    fecha_publicacion =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['fecha_publicacion']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Bolsa de empleo y TDRS"
```

Lo que hice fue borrar lo siguiente:
`cargar_archivo = models.FileField(upload_to='media',blank=True,null=True)`
Hice las migraciones y luego probé subir solo el resto (Solo es texto) y bualá, funcionó pero obviamente necesito subir archivos para que mi aplicación esté completa, si alguien pudiera saber una solución para esto se los agradecería demasiado, les comparto mi archivo settings si de algo sirve

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-=-ft)-0j-si_7^%h42@f&z8sysl2xuzp&#ed)r*e47e&e4-m^q'
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mancuerna.org']


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'inicio',
    'baseconocimiento',
    'publicaciones', 
    'juntadirectiva',
    'informacionpublica',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app.wsgi.application'


# Base de datos
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD':'',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-es'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
MEDIA_URL = "/home/mancuernaorg/public_html/media_cdn/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/mancuernaorg/public_html/static_root'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/mancuernaorg/public_html/media_cdn'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

HELP (Para más información los requerimientos que instalé son, Django, mysql Client y Pillow)